# Linux user space and kernel space communication

Tags: linux

I have a user space application and a kernel character driver `/dev/myfile`. The user space opens the `/dev/myfile` and writes a command to the file. The kernel takes the command, executes it, and replaces the entire command in the file with response message.

Now in user space I run a poll on the file to see if there is any write operation on the file by the kernel. Once the poll method exits, I read file content and display on terminal.

Now my question is on the poll method:

```
struct pollfd fds[1];
fds[0].fd = fd;
fds[0].events = POLLIN | POLLERR | POLLRDNORM;
fds[0].revents = 0;

n = poll(fds, 1, POLL_TIMEOUT);
```

I want the poll to block until kernel writes some data to the file. Remember, I am user space application even i open file and write a command on the file
but the poll method must not exit wait condition once user space application write something to the file i want the poll method to exit only when the kernel completes writing something to the file. so that user space application can read

1) now can any one give me a solution for such situation.

2) one solution i have in mind is write the data to the file and then open a pthread and
   call poll() method inside the thread i tried this method but i found that poll exits i
   don't know the reason why. but when i read the data from the file i get 0 bytes.

Comment: first of all, fix the `.` key on your keyboard. There should be one of them at the end of each sentence.

Comment: @Barmar Fixing this is actually making my head hurt.

Comment: I applaud you for trying...

Comment: Maybe use a semaphore instead of polling on the file itself?

Comment: i cannot modify the kernel so i must use poll method because that is how big giant companies have implemented

Comment: Err, are you trying to turn an non-blocking poll into a blocking one? I think that's known as a read :-)

Comment: poll() blocks until one of the events occurs. specified in the event field

Answer (score 0):

> i found that poll exits i don't know the reason why.

The reason might be that your character driver's `file_operations` function `poll` is faulty. We could maybe tell if you showed this function.